# Problem with showing custom html.twig content

Tags: 8, navigation

im making a custom menu for the homepage. My issue is that whenever I change **block--system-menu-block.html.twig** to something else that it suggest in the debugging like for example: **block--system-menu-block--main.html.twig** or **block--hoofdnavigatie.html.twig** it's not showing up anymore. I've cleared cache, switched themes, but nothing works. It does show up in the dubugging tool that firefox has but theres 0 content in it.. Am I doing something wrong >?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried this on my site and used main navigation and it worked. block--mainnavigation.html.twig

What you can check:

1. Of course check if you have some typo in file name, or try with
   default navigation to see if it works.
2. https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914 Try to disable Twig cache while you are developing.
3. Try to use cache rebuild with Drush https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/cache/cache-rebuild/

I don't think that you are doing something wrong, problem is with caching I believe.

Comment: I think it was something with the cache like you said. I tried those 3 steps and its fixed :) still dont know what the problem causer was tho